# It is possible to use new csproj format to build for .NET Framework Client Profile?

Tags: csproj

I am trying to manually update a new csproj file to configure building for .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile.

This works correctly

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>NET40</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

but this generates an error

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>NET40</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Client</TargetFrameworkProfile>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

```
'project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client'. 
Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 
'net40-client' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
```

Is it possible to use new csproj format e.g. <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> to build for .NET Framework Client Profile?

Comment: Have I tried adding "net40-client" to the "TargetFrameworks" tag as it says in error?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this variant too.
`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net40-client</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>`
The error is "Error NETSDK1013 The TargetFramework value 'net40-client' was not recognized. It may be misspelled. If not, then the TargetFrameworkIdentifier and/or TargetFrameworkVersion properties must be specified explicitly."
I don't see another way now except to perform a conditional build, exclude all functionality that is not supported by Client Profile Frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<TargetFramework>net40-client</TargetFramework>
<TargetFrameworkIdentifier>.NETFramework</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Client</TargetFrameworkProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a package for this, all you have to do is to replace the first line of your `csproj` with:

```xml
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras/2.0.54">
```

Then you have some new target frameworks available such as `net40-client`, so

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net40-client</TargetFrameworks>
```

will now work.

See the project page (https://github.com/novotnyllc/MSBuildSdkExtras) if you want more information.